# How to improve PreLoadMe script to support browsers with disabled JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all, this script (by [Niklaus Gerber](https://github.com/niklausgerber/PreLoadMe)) works, but there's one problem. Once I set it up, it starts from CSS styles by covering whole page with div. Then script comes to uncover fully loaded site, however, it also locks browsers with disabled JavaScript (infinite loading).

Can someone help me to unlock those users, by changing this script or suggest me something more friendly for also those folks? (it's not online yet).

The code is:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#status').fadeOut();animation
        $('#preloader').delay(350)\.fadeOut('slow');
        $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    })
```

For the HTML:

```
<div id="preloader">

    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {

    overflow: scroll;
}

#preloader {

    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:99;
}

#status {

    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    background-image:url(../img/status.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any sugestions.

Comment: What about showing `<noscript>` message to inform user to enable javascript to use your site?

Comment: Thank you for answer, yes I was considering <noscript>. However, I try to find a way to give the same or at least similar experience for guests. If I was the user, I would expect that dev will care also for me, the user who chose not to use JavaScript, no matter what the reason was. As devs, we have great power, would be shame to care only for ourselves, and looking at user with our point of view :) BUT, that's still one option, thank you.

Comment: Ahem - you cant improve a script so that it runs at times that running scripts is disabled. That's just ridiculous. What you **can** do however, is make the site work without the pre-loader. If JS is available, you can then use it to make use of the pre-loader. Just like you can make a page suitable for noscript submit forms by default, but if enabled, you can use JS to change them so the submission happens using ajax.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and there's a problem. The class I call when page loads, is controlled by script. I don't know how to call that class, only when JS is supported. Hope to find and solution here, any advice how to improve script so it can be omitted in this case.

Comment: Well if I have disabled scripts on my browser, I not your novice user and I know what are the consequences. Or at least I will be able to l enable script for your site or walk away. Better option will be to have alternate page and link to that in `<noscript>` just like **skip into** in good ol' flash intros.

Comment: I did something like this in the past for old IE's. Solution works great, but it's too much time to maintain two versions of the same page. Anyway, thank you, it's still another option to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this very simple solution

In your js add `$('body').addClass('jsSupport');`

and in your css hide the preloader by default, so when there is no JavaScript it will not show on screen.

```
#preloader{
  display:none;/*hide when no js*/
}
```

When JavaScript exist, you can show it on screen using the extra css class.

```
.jsSupport #preloader {

    display:block;/*show when js is supported*/
}
```

You can see how I set up the code here

[Demo](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/pJrQVX)

You can disable the browser's JavaScript here to test it out

[Full screen demo](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/full/pJrQVX/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did, but with second script - so another request comes, and unnecesary extra loading time came (paradox). I will try your solution. But for the best performance, in which line would you suggest to put your line of code `$('body').addClass('jsSupport');` ? After `$(window).load(function()` line ?

Comment: @equi I would suggest adding it before $(window).load(function() and after jquery initiation, so that the preloader will be available as soon as the page load. For best performances I would suggest using pure javascript only so you don't need to wait for Jquery to initiate.....

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className+=' jsSupport'`

Comment: Hello again, I was unable to add either line to jQuery or pure JavaScript. Tried inline or external files, without any result (preloader is not called anymore). **EDIT:** It is working like a charm, my misspell :) It's faster with pure JS, you're right (starts immediately while page apperars).